# Mongoose best practice for registering schema with dynamic collection names

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, koa

I have a dynamic collection creation for each user connecting to database, so the collection name is {userID}-{collection_name}.
For each model I'm exporting function that returns mongoose model like this

```
module.exports = function (userId) {
    return mongoose.model(
        'Device',
        DeviceSchema,
        userId + '-' + config.collection_names.device);
}
```

Everything worked fine until I started referencing schemas. My DeviceSchema

```
var DeviceSchema = new Schema(
    {
        _id: {type: String, required: true, index: true},
        name: {type: String, required: true},        
        sensors: [{type: String, ref: 'Sensor'}]
    }
);
```

Now when I want to find user's devices with sensors populated

```
var devices = yield models.Device(userId).find({}).populate('sensors').exec()
```

I got MissingSchemaError of course

```
MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "Sensor".
```

I know I have to register all schemas before referencing, but this looks kinda odd to trying to load schema for every request for example like this

```
try {
    var devices = yield models.Device(userId).find({}).populate('sensors').exec()
}
catch {
    models.Sensor(userId);
    var devices = yield models.Device(userId).find({}).populate('sensors').exec()
}
```

I'm afraid this approach is not ok with best practices and I'm not sure how it is performance wise.
So how should I design something like this? And is it ok to differ "user's" database by prefix in collection name?

Comment: You really should be "retrieving" your "model" via `mongoose.model('MyModel')`. That means along with the actual "physical" collection name then that part "needs" to be named individually as well. Otherwise something else calling "MyModel" suddenly ends up working with a different collection than you expect.

Comment: Ok, but then is there any way to populate field with specifying collection name? I have ID of sensor in "sensors" array, but when I call populate('sensors'), there is nothing populated. I also tried to  specify a model with collection name in population with populate({path: 'sensors', model: mongoose('Sensor', '123-sensors')), but with the same results.